# Is there a right way to pass data into a React component from the HTML page?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app like this.

```
var X = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    fetch(this.props.feed).then(...);
  }
  render: function() {
    return <div>{this.props.feed}</div>
  }
});
```

The feed prop is used to get a JSON feed in componentDidMount that's unique for a particular customer.

It would be convenient to pass data into my React app from the HTML to parameterise it:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app" feed='custom_feed.json'></div>
  </body>
</html
```

My current solution looks like this:

```
var root = document.getElementById('app');
var feed = root.getAttribute('feed')
ReactDOM.render(<X feed={feed}/>, root);
```

This obviously works, but it feels like there ought to be a more idiomatic solution. Is there a more React way to do this?

Comment: I'm not ready to convert my app into a SPA. My HTML is generated with a ruby script. The React component is actually a fairly small part of a static page. In Angular I could simply drop `<x z='z'></x>` onto the page. 

I'm obviously being wrongheaded about this.

Comment: Came here from Django, similar use case

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I have used `data-` attributes for various props, then passed all the props using destructuring [`{...dataset}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset), for example:

HTML:

```
<div id="app" data-feed='custom_feed.json' data-someprop='value'></div>
```

JS:

```
var root = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<X {...(root.dataset)} />, root);
```

<strike>Edit: [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbpkj5px/)</strike>
Edit 2018: [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbpkj5px/160/)

Comment: This is nice, but how is it different to getAttribute?

Comment: 1. `data-` attributes are intended to be used for this purpose instead of inventing invalid attributes, 2. You don't have to type `.getAttribute` for each extra prop you want to pass, all of them are in the `dataset`.

Comment: But then you can only pass flat data via `dataset`. What if one needs to pass in the whole array/object?

Comment: @jayarjo it would be possible to put a JSON string in a `data-` attribute, but I think when it comes to a lot of data it would be better to just print the object in a `<script>` tag, then reference it from the component.

Comment: Damn it @pawel i love you, you solved my day ! :) :)

Comment: so dirty... just my type of hacks.

Comment: this is a great solution!

Comment: Note that passing values will be transformed to LowerCase, so passing ```data-initialValue='0'``` you get ```dataset.initialvalue```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem, dynamically generated pages that contain data relevant to the React stuff.

I just declared them in the global scope ..

```
<script>
  window.foobles = [12,453,12];
  window.bahs = ["bah", "bah", "black sheep"];
</script>
```

.. THEN ..

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Component
    foobles={window.foobles}
    bahs={window.bah}
  />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Obviously, from a namespacing perspective, this can have some drawbacks :)

Answer (score 4):

You can just pass your data when mounting the component like so:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script>
    const data = { foo: 'bar' };
    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(MyComponent, data),
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[React Habitat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-habitat) is a framework that facilitates this if you want something reusable and extendable.

You register React components like this

```
containerBuilder.register(Feed).as('Feed')
```

Then define targets in the HTML like this with props

```
<div data-component="Feed" data-prop-feed-src="/custom_feed.json">
```

React Habitat will wire these up any time it appears in the HTML.

*Disclosure: I am one of the head maintainers of this framework.*