# Render Url dynamically in ReactJS depending on the environment

Tags: python, django, reactjs, docker

I am using ReactJS in the front end wherein upon clicking a submit button, it calls 4 apis in dev-environment:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ParameterForm url_schema="http://192.168.99.100/api/v1/var" url_uischema="http://192.168.99.100/api/v1/ui" url_data="http://192.168.99.100/api/v1/data" url_submit="http://192.168.99.100/api/v1/calculated" />,
  document.getElementById('form')
);
```

I am using docker to run the application locally which has a `settings` folder with `base.py`, `local.py` and `production.py`.
For Production-env, I want the apis to be called something like these:

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <ParameterForm url_schema="http://xyz:8000/api/v1/var" url_uischema="http://xyz:8000/api/v1/ui" url_data="http://xyz:8000/api/v1/data" url_submit="http://xyz:8000/api/v1/calculated" />,
      document.getElementById('form')
    );
```

I need to know whether is there a way in which these apis can be declared either in `local.py` or `production.py` and can be called dynamically in my DOM based on the environment in which I run my app.

Comment: `<ParameterForm { ...url_config } />`, and you render an object like `window.url_config = { "url_schema" : "{{ URL_SCHEMA }}" ....etc... }` into the HTML template.

Comment: Or use `data-` attributes on the `form` element, e.g. `<form data-url_schema="{{ URL_SCHEMA }}">` and `{...form.dataset}`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36545557/4879

Comment: @pawel the apis are to be declared in `local.py` or `production.py` in `local.py` the apis  are: `URL_SCHEMA = "http://192.168.99.100/api/v1/var" URL_UISCHEMA="http://192.168.99.100/api/v1/ui" URL_DATA="http://192.168.99.100/api/v1/data" URL_SUBMIT="http://192.168.99.100/api/v1/calculated"` and in `production.py` the urls are: `URL_SCHEMA ="http://xyz:8000/api/v1/var" URL_UISCHEMA="http://xyz:8000/api/v1/ui" URL_DATA="http://xyz:8000/api/v1/data" URL_SUBMIT="http://xyz:8000/api/v1/calculated"` now I need to call these urls in my `app.js` in React DOM depending on the environment I am running.

Comment: @pawel any idea on how to call the apis depending on the environment?